# Is virtualenv recommended even for single django based application on a server?

Tags: python, django, virtualenv

If we just want to host single django application on a VPS or some cloud instance, is it still benefitial to use virtualenv ?
Or will it be an overkill , and better to use global python setup instead, as only one django application say Project X , will be hosted on that server ?

Does virtualenv provide any major benefits for a single application setup in a production  environment that I might not be aware of ? eg. django upgradation, cron scripts , etc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd recommend always using virtualenv, because it makes your environment more reproducible -- you can version your dependencies alongside your application, you're not tied to the versions of the python packages in your system repository, and if you need to replicate your environment elsewhere, you can do that even if you're not running exactly the same OS underneath.